# How do I know user drag left of right?

Tags: jquery, html, sencha-touch

I have some `div` in my page that when an user drags one of them to left, the `div` would fade out.

My question is:

How can I be able to detect when the users drags to the left or to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You must add this inside `droppable` init, inside `drop` param function.

I dont know sencha-touch, but his logic looks really, really ugly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYfNb/64/)

```
if($(ui.helper).hasClass('ui-draggable')){
//draggable item

    if(ui.position.left < 0){

        alert('Draggable dragged to left');
    }
    else if(ui.position.left > 0){

       alert('Draggable dragged to right'); 
    }

    if(ui.position.top < 0){

        alert('Draggable dragged to top');
    }
    else if(ui.position.top > 0){

       alert('Draggable dragged to bottom'); 
    }
}
else{
//sortable item

    var originalPosition = ui.helper.data().sortableItem.originalPosition;

    if(ui.position.left < originalPosition.left){

        alert('Draggable dragged to left');
    }
    else if(ui.position.left > originalPosition.left){

       alert('Draggable dragged to right'); 
    }

    if(ui.position.top < originalPosition.top){

        alert('Draggable dragged to top');
    }
    else if(ui.position.top > originalPosition.top){

       alert('Draggable dragged to bottom'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry,can you give me an example

Comment: You want know element was dropped to right of start position, or was dropped on right side of red box?

Comment: Sortable and draggable elements?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tYfNb/63/ sencha-touch have really odd logic. Param `position` of event variable is different by type of draggable element. Draggable element `position` returns different types of values, from difference of start position to dragging-off position, to current position which must be calculated with additional param - `ui.helper.data().sortableItem.originalPosition`. I have spent many time for this, this is really ugly logic. But i hope i helped You.